# How to hand over complex string to CMD using R?

Tags: r, cmd, geospatial, raster, rgdal

to georeference an image, I want to hand over a complex string to the command line via R using `system()`. Unfortunately I could not solve the problem till now.

I want to hand over following string to the CMD line:
gdal_translate -of GTiff -gcp 0.0 0.0 5.50000 5.80000 -gcp 1.0 949.0 5.20000 4.40000 -gcp 1024.0 949.0 6.50000 4.20000 -gcp 1024.0 1.0 6.70000 5.60000 "D:/User_1/01_test_data/dataset.flt" "C:/Users/User_1/AppData/Local/Temp/dataset.flt"

The problem seems to be, that I have got whitespaces as well as quotation marks included in that string. I have already tried `paste()` and `paste0()` but failed.

```
system(command = paste(gdal_translate -of GTiff -gcp 0.0 0.0 5.50000 5.80000 -gcp 1.0 949.0 5.20000 4.40000 -gcp 1024.0 949.0 6.50000 4.20000 -gcp 1024.0 1.0 6.70000 5.60000 "D:/User_1/01_test_data/dataset.flt" "C:/Users/User_1/AppData/Local/Temp/dataset.flt"))

Error: unexpected symbol in "system(command = paste(gdal_translate -of GTiff"
```

Do you have any suggestions, how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have no " around your string. Do:

```
system(command = "gdal_translate -of GTiff -gcp 0.0149883 0.0166216 5.47596 5.81301 -gcp 8.25477e-06 949 5.20347 4.39893 -gcp 1024 949 6.46477 4.23317 -gcp 1024 2.68374e-07 6.73943 5.64718 'D:/User_1/01_test_data/dataset.flt' 'C:/Users/User_1/AppData/Local/Temp/dataset.flt'")
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your help! i did not know that you have to use different quotation marks like 'blablabla' and "blablabla". now it is working!

Comment: Usually the combination of " and ' does the trick when you need nested string. Otherwise you have the escape character, eg. " bla \"bla\" bla"

Comment: For the dynamic way, use `paste` or `paste0` (in `paste` you can specify the separator with the parameter `sep`, the default being space, in `paste0` no space are printed between arguments). So if you want in your example put the output format from a variable defined as `out="GTiff"` you can do : `system(command = paste0("gdal_translate -of ",out," -gcp 0.0149883 0.0166216 5.47596 5.81301 -gcp 8.25477e-06 949 5.20347 4.39893 -gcp 1024 949 6.46477 4.23317 -gcp 1024 2.68374e-07 6.73943 5.64718 'D:/User_1/01_test_data/dataset.flt' 'C:/Users/User_1/AppData/Local/Temp/dataset.flt'"))`

Comment: you are too fast! thanks a lot for answering the questions before i even formulated them in a nice way! :D

question was...:

do you also know how to combine the string in a dynamic way and pass it to the cmd line? e.g.:

```
dir1 <- "D:/User1/01_test_data/dataset.flt"
dir2 <- "D:/User1/02_temp_data/dataset.flt"

var1 <- c("0.0 0.0 5.50000 5.80000")
var2 <- c("1.0 949.0 5.20000 4.40000")

system(paste('gdal_translate -of GTiff -gcp ', var1, ' -gcp ', var2, dir1, dir2)